# Redirect a PHP populating from MySQL Query

Tags: php, redirect

I need to redirect users from the page resources/?group=168 to resources/?group=205.

Is the best way to do this in htaccess, php redirect, or possibly to switch the case in the index.php?

I've tried without success:

**htaccess**

```
Redirect resources/?group=168 http://www.site.com/resources/?group=205
```

**Case Switch**

```
switch ($id) { case '168': $id = 205; break;}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want to redirect? Is this the only one, will there be more redirects?

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL queries?

Comment: I'm redirecting from a page that we used to store newsletters to a new location. This is the only redirect for now. Maybe I worded it wrong, but the pages are all stored in the database vs. php files and it pulls each page into the index.php by number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to permanently use this group ID versus the other one, I would do it in htacces or Apache config that way you can send a proper 3XX series response header to let the browser (and search engine spiders) know that this is a new location for that resource.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^resources/\?group=168$ /resources/?group=205 [R=301,L]
```

If your exact URI is not going to be /resources/?group=168 then you might need to do a litt different pattern like:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/(\?|.*&)group=168(&.*$|$) /resources/$1group=205$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to get each of these to work in our setup, and haven't had any luck. Ideally I'd like to use .htaccess but I'm not getting any results with the rewriterule. I've added it to the .htaccess in the root folder, and I'm guessing the $ symbol is for anything that may come after the 168. It's not reacting at all though.

Comment: The $ symbol means end of string.  This will only match the literal URI of /resources/?group=168.  If there are going to be other parameters possibly passed, then you would want to do something different.  See my edit above.

Comment: I've tried adding the specific redirect and your code to the root, html, and resource folder and it doesn't seem to make a difference in any of them. What folder should that sit in to help take out some of my guess work? Thanks!

Comment: That rule can be in either your main webroot or in your apache config file.  NOte that if placing it in your web root you need to AllowOverride in your main Apache config (this is not on by default).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 168) {
  header('Location: http://www.site.com/resources/?group=205');
}
```

if the header redirect doesn't work, use javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.site.com/resources/?group=205"
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an `if` statement myself:

```
if ($id == '168') $id = 205;
```

But it really depends on your needs, I suppose. If you want the URL bar to reflect the redirect, I would suggest .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this would work but I'm realizing I need the htaccess for anyone using a previous link to the page.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what the `switch` is suppose to do (by itself) in your example but how about

```
switch($_GET['group']) {
    case 168: $redirGrp = 205;break;
}
if(!empty($redirGrp)) header("Location:?group=$redirGrp");
```